# want to add a active button in react for same section using useRef

Tags: reactjs

Try to add active class using use-ref and try to toggle the class for same section whenever I click, but it's not working.
so could anyone please just tell me how can I add active or toggle class for the same section , no matter how many section I have , whenever I click any one of these, will active the class

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
function Homewrapcpy() {
  const togglSc = useRef();
  const handleActiveBtn = (i) => {
    togglSc.current.classList.toggle("jstbtn");
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* one section */}
      <div className="pstfeedbackbtn">
        <div className="dflx lverct" onClick={handleActiveBtn} ref={togglSc}>
          <div className="svg">
            <div className="svg">
              <svg
                width="26"
                height="26"
                viewBox="0 0 26 26"
                fill="none"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M24.7 25.9858C24.5838 26.0047 24.4652 26.0047 24.349 25.9858L17.316 24.0372C15.9218 24.4847 14.4643 24.7041 13 24.6867C9.64001 24.767 6.38513 23.5132 3.94844 21.1999C1.51175 18.8867 0.0919208 15.7026 0 12.3452C0.0919208 8.98777 1.51175 5.80366 3.94844 3.49039C6.38513 1.17712 9.64001 -0.0766894 13 0.00363456C16.36 -0.0766894 19.6149 1.17712 22.0516 3.49039C24.4882 5.80366 25.9081 8.98777 26 12.3452C25.9975 14.7458 25.2628 17.0887 23.894 19.0616L25.909 24.258C25.988 24.4768 26.0067 24.7128 25.9633 24.9413C25.9198 25.1698 25.8158 25.3825 25.662 25.5571C25.5405 25.6917 25.3921 25.7994 25.2264 25.8732C25.0607 25.947 24.8814 25.9854 24.7 25.9858ZM17.264 21.322C17.3807 21.3092 17.4983 21.3092 17.615 21.322L22.542 22.6991L21.242 19.2954C21.1543 19.0822 21.1249 18.8495 21.1569 18.6212C21.1889 18.3929 21.281 18.1772 21.424 17.9963C22.6904 16.3831 23.3854 14.3955 23.4 12.3452C23.3084 9.67681 22.1626 7.1534 20.2134 5.32732C18.2643 3.50125 15.6705 2.52125 13 2.60185C10.3295 2.52125 7.73572 3.50125 5.78657 5.32732C3.83742 7.1534 2.69162 9.67681 2.6 12.3452C2.69162 15.0135 3.83742 17.5369 5.78657 19.363C7.73572 21.1891 10.3295 22.1691 13 22.0885C14.3047 22.0865 15.5987 21.8534 16.822 21.4C16.9637 21.3486 17.1133 21.3222 17.264 21.322V21.322Z"
                  fill="#070707"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span>345</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* one section */}
      <div className="pstfeedbackbtn">
        <div className="dflx lverct" onClick={handleActiveBtn} ref={togglSc}>
          <div className="svg">
            <svg
              width="26"
              height="26"
              viewBox="0 0 26 26"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M24.7 25.9858C24.5838 26.0047 24.4652 26.0047 24.349 25.9858L17.316 24.0372C15.9218 24.4847 14.4643 24.7041 13 24.6867C9.64001 24.767 6.38513 23.5132 3.94844 21.1999C1.51175 18.8867 0.0919208 15.7026 0 12.3452C0.0919208 8.98777 1.51175 5.80366 3.94844 3.49039C6.38513 1.17712 9.64001 -0.0766894 13 0.00363456C16.36 -0.0766894 19.6149 1.17712 22.0516 3.49039C24.4882 5.80366 25.9081 8.98777 26 12.3452C25.9975 14.7458 25.2628 17.0887 23.894 19.0616L25.909 24.258C25.988 24.4768 26.0067 24.7128 25.9633 24.9413C25.9198 25.1698 25.8158 25.3825 25.662 25.5571C25.5405 25.6917 25.3921 25.7994 25.2264 25.8732C25.0607 25.947 24.8814 25.9854 24.7 25.9858ZM17.264 21.322C17.3807 21.3092 17.4983 21.3092 17.615 21.322L22.542 22.6991L21.242 19.2954C21.1543 19.0822 21.1249 18.8495 21.1569 18.6212C21.1889 18.3929 21.281 18.1772 21.424 17.9963C22.6904 16.3831 23.3854 14.3955 23.4 12.3452C23.3084 9.67681 22.1626 7.1534 20.2134 5.32732C18.2643 3.50125 15.6705 2.52125 13 2.60185C10.3295 2.52125 7.73572 3.50125 5.78657 5.32732C3.83742 7.1534 2.69162 9.67681 2.6 12.3452C2.69162 15.0135 3.83742 17.5369 5.78657 19.363C7.73572 21.1891 10.3295 22.1691 13 22.0885C14.3047 22.0865 15.5987 21.8534 16.822 21.4C16.9637 21.3486 17.1133 21.3222 17.264 21.322V21.322Z"
                fill="#070707"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
          <span>345</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: you need to have different ref's in that case ....

Comment: I want to use the same ref, and if we can't do that using ref, how to use signle useState for all section